# Delphi Drawing Focus

Tags: delphi, winapi, drawing, focus

I'm using the following code to make my form entirely transparent so that clicks can go "through" it to other windows.

```
SetWindowPos( handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0,0,
                   SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOMOVE );
SetWindowLong(form1.handle,GWL_EXSTYLE,WS_EX_TOPMOST or WS_EX_LAYERED);
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(form1.handle,RGB(0,0,0),200,LWA_ALPHA or LWA_COLORKEY);
```

My problem is that when I begin drawing on the form, these drawings can be clicked on and the Delphi form will take focus. I want to be able to draw without these drawings being "clickable".

I hope I was clear enough. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` extended window style too.

Comment: Thanks so much! It's been bugging me for the longest time.

Answer (score 1):

Either give your window the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT window style, or handle the WM_NCHITTEST message and return HTTRANSPARENT.  see this related post for an example
[(Windows API) WM_PAINT Mouse problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301089/windows-api-wm-paint-mouse-problems/2301173#2301173)